# Why does sourcing a file inside a conditional block behave different than outside of one?

Tags: shell, zsh, zshrc

Can someone please explain why the first snippet in my `~/.zshrc` works and the second produces an error?

When written like this (no error):

```
BASE16_SHELL="$HOME/.config/base16-shell/"
[ -n "$PS1" ] && [ -s "$BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh" ] && source "$BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh"
base16_classic-dark
```

When written like this (error):

```
if [ -d "$HOME/.config/base16-shell" ]; then
  BASE16_SHELL="$HOME/.config/base16-shell/"
  [ -n "$PS1" ] && [ -s "$BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh" ] && source "$BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh"
  base16_classic-dark
fi
```

In the failing version, the error I see when opening a new terminal window is:

```
/home/freddiehaddad/.zshrc:44: command not found: base16_classic-dark
```

To be clear, I'm not trying to use both snippets at the same time.  What I'm trying to do is make my `.zshrc` file more robust by only executing code blocks if the actual dependencies exist.

UPDATE:

I'm wondering if this has something to do with the behavior of `source`.

The following works:

```
BASE16_SHELL="$HOME/.config/base16-shell/"
if [ -n "$PS1" ] && [ -s "$BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh" ]; then
  source "$BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh"
fi
base16_classic-dark
```

But putting the `base16_classic-dark` command inside the `if` block fails with the same error:

```
BASE16_SHELL="$HOME/.config/base16-shell/"
if [ -n "$PS1" ] && [ -s "$BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh" ]; then
  source "$BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh"
  base16_classic-dark
fi
```

This also fails:

```
if [ -n "$PS1" ] && [ -s "$BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh" ]; then
  BASE16_SHELL="$HOME/.config/base16-shell/"
  source "$BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh"
fi
base16_classic-dark
```

Strangely, this works but still outputs the same error message:

```
BASE16_SHELL="$HOME/.config/base16-shell/"
if [ -n "$PS1" ] && [ -s "$BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh" ]; then
  source "$BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh"
  base16_classic-dark
fi
```

UPDATE:

Continuing to experiment and try to understand the behavior, it seems like the issue is the scope/visibility of the `BASE16_SHELL` variable.  Attempting to prefix it with `export` doesn't matter.  And to be honest, at this point, everything I'm doing is just pure guessing and no logic behind what I'm doing.

Comment: Please add `set -x` before running the smallest piece of code that reproduces the problem, so that we can see what’s actually going on.

Comment: Oh, and delete all the other failing cases and whatever else you did from the text. Keep only the [smallest, reproducible case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and its debug output.

Comment: Provided that both code snippets run in an interactive zsh, I don't see a reason why they would behave differently. I would simply run it with `-x` turned on and see where things go astray.

Comment: BTW, the error message makes me wonder: What kind of command is ` base16_classic-dark` **supposed** to be? External executable, or shell function?

Comment: base16_classic-dark is an alias that gets setup by the snippet in my .zshrc.  It sets the terminal theme colors to the classic-dark theme.  Base16 Shell is a set of themes for terminals.  https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell